# Running Spring Clound Config and Eureka on same server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

We are trying to create a dashboard for our application as a single point of entry/configuration. For this we will build and UI and would like to run Spring Cloud [Config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) and [Eureka](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/) on same instance. Is there any reason why we should not do this and if not is it possible?

Comment: Well I'd ask the other way around. Why do you want to do that? To overcome same origin policies? In that case I'd build a "frontend" boot app which serves the UI and proxies Eureka and Config server.

Comment: The ideea is/was to create a spring boot app with some ui(administration) capabilities and also integrate the configuration and eureka service. This would simplify the deployment process for us as we are considering deploying to [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) where we could deploy a jar. What you propose will force us to wrap everything in a docker image. I am not saying it`s a bad ideea but we would have a separate deployment procedure just for this service

Comment: Why do you think you can't wrap this as a jar?

Comment: I presume i would need 3 separate spring "bootified" apps . Maybe yo ucan share a hit on how to wrap this 3 apps in a single jar and start then the "normal" way with `java -jar ....`

Comment: I do understand your idea but this is also somehow contradicting the idea of microservices. BTW: why would you need Euraka if you have only one jar?

Comment: We would have around 4 or 5 services running. What we are trying to builld is a kind of dashboard and we would like the dashboard service act as a configuration/discovery service also ... this would simplify the distribution a bit for us

Comment: But why do you then have an issue running Config and Eureka on separate services? One of those would be discoverable through the other. And then you just create your dashboard one as a third service that serves the static application and uses Zuul to proxy through the requests to Eureka and Config Server.

Comment: We are trying to limit the number of services we will deploy. But it seems we wont get away with that :)

Comment: Well there might be a way but I wouldn't try this cause you'll most likely interfere cause you have to change url structures to be conflict free.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@mvlupan, there is nothing keeping you from using together. That is one of the reasons we created `@EnableEurekaServer` and `@EnableConfigServer`.

`pom.xml` snippet.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`Application.java` snippet

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoconfigandeurekaserverApplication { /*...*/}
```

`application.properties` snippet (so eureka and config server don't clash).

```
spring.cloud.config.server.prefix=/config
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now i`m wondering if it makes sense..because the configuration services is used to provide configuration across environments (dev/prod/etc)..and Eureka seems tied to a certain env where it connects different services. Does Eureka have this capability (working with multiple env) ? Does it make sense?

Comment: @mvlupan so what did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

For high availability in production environment there should be at least 2 instances running on different servers.

Both ConfigServer and EurekaServer should have 2 instances.

Personally I prefer to see ConfigServer and EurekaServer running as one process as @spencergibb has shown.

There are config-first or discovery-first approches on what runs first.

P.S.
I expect that your Dashboard application will be separate from ConfigServer/EurekaServer,
so its own issues would not affect business critical parts.